# How are 4 and 5 digit hex color codes represented?

Tags: html, css, colors

When I use #FF22 or #FF444, what rules turn it into a color? I know that hex codes should be 6 digits, or 3, but this works in chrome.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in chrome.

Comment: Neither one of the two hex codes worked for me in Chrome either... Can you make a fiddle showing this working?

Comment: When you state *this works in chrome* please give an example.

Comment: there are systems with 4 digit `#rgba` so `#FE12` becomes `#FFEE11` with opaticy of `22/ff≈0.13` and 5 digit `#rgbaa` so `#FE144` will be `#FFEE11` with opacity of `44/ff≈0.26` yet i never seen such conversion working in browser

Comment: Pretty harsh downvoting, everyone - it's a good question based on curiosity, no need to slam him.  Anyway, I found this because the color highlighter in Sublime makes a background color somehow with 4 and 5 digits. Looks like it's just taking the first 3 and repeating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no 4 digit hex color. 3 digit hex color is converted into 6 digit hex color by copying each character next to each to other. For example, #f0f is expanded to #ff00ff.

Comment: In 2016, Chrome 52 and Firefox 49 added 4 and 8 digit hex color codes with the last 1 or 2 digits respectively corresponding to the alpha channel. 5 digits should still give undefined behavior. As others have commented, support in all browsers may take a while: https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/